# How to toggle button text when pressed in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to change button text when pressed using PyQt5. I have a populated table with a button in each row. Initially the button should display "Play" and once pressed it should display "Pause".

[image]

I populate the table and handle button press using the following methods:

```py
def populate_table(self, total, my_songs):
    self.create_rows(total)
    btn_press = 0

    for row in range(total):
        for col in range(4):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(my_songs[row].get_title())
                                                                        .strip('"\'')))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(my_songs[row].get_artist())
                                                                        .strip('"\'')))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(my_songs[row].get_album())
                                                                        .strip('"\'')))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(my_songs[row].get_length())
                                                                        .strip('"\'')))
            # self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 4, QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play'))

            self.btn_play = QPushButton("Play", self)
            self.btn_play.clicked.connect(lambda: self.handle_play_button(self.btn_press))
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 4, self.btn_play)

def handle_play_button(self, btn_press):
    button = QtWidgets.qApp.focusWidget()
    # or button = self.sender()
    index = self.tableWidget.indexAt(button.pos())
    if index.isValid():
        self.btn_press += 1
        print(index.row(), index.column(), btn_press)
        self.btn_play.setText("Pause")  #This does not work
```

This gives me indication which button was pressed so I can proceed to play the song. Following the examples give [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qpushbutton_widget.htm)  I tried using `setText`, but I see no visible text change. Any suggestions on how this can be done? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Mistake on my behalf. Irrespective of which button is pressed, the last button that was created changes to Pause. Can I use `index.row()` to somehow index the button presses to toggle?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never create an attribute in a loop, in your case `self.btn_play` which button will you point to? then to the last and therefore it does not work for us. The button you get it using focusWidget() or with sender if the class is a widget.

```py
def populate_table(self, my_songs):
    self.tableWidget.clear()
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
    for row, data in enumerate(my_songs):
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(self.tableWidget.rowCount())
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(my_songs[row].get_title())
                                                                    .strip('"\'')))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(my_songs[row].get_artist())
                                                                    .strip('"\'')))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(my_songs[row].get_album())
                                                                    .strip('"\'')))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(my_songs[row].get_length())
                                                                    .strip('"\'')))
        btn_play = QtWidgets.QPushButton(text="Play", clicked=self.handle_play_button)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 4, btn_play)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def handle_play_button(self):
    btn = QtWidgets.qApp.focusWidget()
    # btn = self.sender()
    if btn is not None:
        text = btn.text()
        btn.setText("Pause" if text == "Play" else "Play")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected. But I am getting two unexpected argument warning arguments at `btn_play = QtWidgets.QPushButton(text="Play", clicked=self.handle_play_button)`. Im not sure why this is happening

Comment: @Rrz0 try changing to: `btn_play = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Play") btn_play.clicked.connect(self.handle_play_button)`

Comment: Yes, will revert back to the previous syntax, thanks. I also think that the `self.tableWIdget.clear()` command removes the previously set column names, so I will be commenting that out. (Just a pointer for future references)