# Pyqt5 Check pushbutton color and change pushbutton color

Tags: python, pyqt5

I created a pushbutton by PyQt5. The pushbutton's original background-color is gray. If its background-color is gray, its background-color will change to red when I press it. If its background-color is red, it will change to gray when I press it.
The following is my code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 200, 221, 71))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.action)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

    def action(self):
        if self.pushButton.setStyleSheet["background-color"] == "gray":
            self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        else:
            self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")
if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = Ui_MainWindow()
   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   MainWindow.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code has a error in "if" line. I don't know how to check pushbutton background-color.
If I use tkinter to create button. I know how to check button background-color.

```
if self.buttons["bg"] == "gray":
```

But now I want to know how to check pushbutton background-color by using PyQt5.

```
if self.pushButton.setStyleSheet["background-color"] == "gray":
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55567249/11751294) should work out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you're using square brackets (that are used for getting specific items from objects such as lists or dictionaries) against a function.
Also, `setStyleSheet()` is used to *set* the stylesheet while you might want to check against the *existing* stylesheet, which is returned with `styleSheet()`.

This will fix the error and get the color switch working:

```
        if self.pushButton.styleSheet() == "background-color: gray;":
```

I would not suggest this approach anyway, as this will only work as long as the stylesheet *string* is exactly that.

Unfortunately, there's no way to programmatically get properties set through stylesheets.
When using `setStyleSheet`, its contents are internally parsed and processed by Qt, and the properties that are set are *never* exposed; you don't get an "object" you can interact with, so there's no way to do something like `if "background-color" == "gray"`.

This also means that if you use a more complex css, with your approach you'll need to check against *the whole contents* of the style sheet and set it again completely, since `setStyleSheet` completely overwrites the existing one.

If you want to stick with css, you could create a "template" stylesheet (also allowing you to add other properties) and use an internal property to keep track of the color:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    buttonStyleSheet = """
        color: white;
        background-color: {};
    """
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 200, 221, 71))
        self.pushButton.currentBackground = "gray"
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(self.buttonStyleSheet.format(self.pushButton.currentBackground))
        self.pushButton.setText("button")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.action)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

    def action(self):
        if self.pushButton.currentBackground == "gray":
            self.pushButton.currentBackground = "red"
            self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(self.buttonStyleSheet.format("red"))
        else:
            self.pushButton.currentBackground = "gray"
            self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(self.buttonStyleSheet.format("gray"))
```

PS: I strongly suggest you to **not** edit the python files generated by `pyuic` to create your programs; read the official documentation on how to correctly [use the files created with Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code) instead.